# Facing an error while generating VDM using cloud-sdk maven profile

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, maven-profiles

Im trying to generate VDMs using the below metadata-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0"
    xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema Namespace="myService" xml:lang="en" sap:schema-version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
            <Annotation Term="Core.SchemaVersion" String="1.0.0" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm"/>
            <EntityType Name="myPlant" sap:content-version="1">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Plant"/>
                    <PropertyRef Name="PlantName"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Plant" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Plant" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="PlantName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="30" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="PurchasinPlant" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="ValuationArea" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Valuation Area" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="PlantCustomer" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="CustomerNoPlant" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="PlantSupplier" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Sppl. No. Plnt" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="DefaultPurchasingOrganization" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Purchasing Org." sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="FactoryCalendar" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="2" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Factory Calend." sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="SalesOrganization" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Sales Org. ICB" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="AddressId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Address" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="PlantCategory" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Plant cat." sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
                <Property Name="Distributionchannel" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="2" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Distrib.channel" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
            </EntityType>
            
            
            <EntityContainer Name="myService_Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
                <EntitySet Name="myPlantSet" EntityType="myService.myPlant" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:pageable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
            </EntityContainer>
            <atom:link rel="self" href="https://sap/myService/$metadata" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
            <atom:link rel="latest-version" href="https://sap/myService/$metadata" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

On running the maven profile, I get below error-

Error: URI=file:/C:../src/main/resources/connectedsystem/metadata/myService.xml Line=5: Document root element "edmx:Edmx", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
Error: URI=file:/C:../src/main/resources/connectedsystem/metadata/myService.xml Line=5: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default ErrorHandler to print the first 0  errors.  Please call the setErrorHandler method to fix this.
Error: URI=file:/C:../src/main/resources/connectedsystem/metadata/myService.xml Line=5: Document root element "edmx:Edmx", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
Error: URI=file:/C:../src/main/resources/connectedsystem/metadata/myService.xml Line=5: Document is invalid: no grammar found.

The cloud-sdk version used is 3.42.0

Answer (score 0):

These error messages typically occur because the XML document is not valid according to the XML standard. However, this does not jeopardize the code generation in most of the cases. So please tell us whether the code generation also fails.

I can successfully generate the code using the provided metadata, hence I believe there is no problem.